# Locate text in a page by using other text in xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

How can I locate some text in a span in one row using other text that's in other span in other row by xpath in selenium, I don't want to traverse by html tags as html template can be changed dynamically and also I don't have a unique Id.

Below is my code with highlighted text as question and answer text :-

```
<div id="surveyquescontent">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="mrQuestionText" style="">**Have you chosen your own date for when your electric bill is due?**</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span style="">
                        <span class="mrQuestionTable" style="display:block;margin-left: 1em;">
                            <span id="Cell.0.0" style="">
                                <label for="_Q1_C0">
                                    <span class="mrSingleText" style="">**Yes**</span>
                                </label>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to select the correct `<tr>` and use `following-sibling::tr` and continue digging to the desired `<span>` for example :

```
//tr[.//span[@class='mrQuestionText']]
/following-sibling::tr[1]
//span[@class='mrSingleText']
```

In above example I'm using `class` attribute value to get correct `<tr>`, you can change it easily to be using text within the `<span>` if you have to, or using both text and class :

```
//tr[.//span[
              @class='mrQuestionText'
                and
              .='Have you chosen your own date for when your electric bill is due?'
            ]]
/following-sibling::tr[1]
//span[@class='mrSingleText']
```